# Недопустимая разметка IronPython Visual studio WPF

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio, ironpython

Здравствуйте. При создании приложения WPF ironpython в visualstudio, студия не обнаруживает IronPython и пишет "Недопустимая разметка", хотя он установлен ( в обозревателе решений видно). Подскажите, как исправить данную ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) питон установлен на компе? 2) путь в его папку есть в переменных путях PATH?

Comment: Установлен, нужно указывать путь к интерпретатору python или же ironpython? К python (3.6.) указан.

Comment: Так, указал путь к IronPython, теперь не написано, что он отсутствует, но ошибка "Недопустимая разметка" так и осталась.

Comment: Ух, не думал, что кто-то использует `IronPython` с `WPF`

Comment: Это было показано в уроке по Python от ITVDN, там у человека всё работало https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-R_VR_Y5g8c&feature=youtu.be&t=1h12m31s

Comment: @TenTens, у вас там в разметке отсутствует `x:Class="..."`

Comment: @АндрейNOP не думаю, что это обязательно, возможно даже наоборот